# How to show a toast if Edittext has no text entered?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 5 edit texts:
1.First name,
2.last name,
3.address,
4,country,
5.postal code

and a submit button.i want to show a toast ,when the user clicks the submit button but still left some fields empty.

thanks for all your comments and support.
I finally found my answer here:
[how to toast a message if editText is empty by clicking button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827559/how-to-toast-a-message-if-edittext-is-empty-by-clicking-button)

Comment: Do you want to show a specific message for each?

Comment: no.just one message.the field is empty.plz enter data.

Answer (score 1):

In the button’s onClick method, you’ll have to look at empty EditText using :

```
if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals(´´ ´´)) {
   //display Toast message
   Toast.makeText(this, « Empty », Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

A if statement is required for each EditText.

You can send a Toast this way :

```
Toast.makeText(this, « Empty », Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

With `switch`? You can't, but you can do it.

To check if an EditText is empty:

```
CharSquence text = someEditText.getText();
boolean empty = text == null || text.toString.isEmpty();
```

Just use that logic for each TextView. You could even make a helper function:

```
public boolean isEmpty(EditText editText) {
    CharSquence text = someEditText.getText();
    return text == null || text.toString.isEmpty();
}
```

And combine the results:

```
boolean hasEmpty = isEmpty(firstName) || isEmpty(lastName) || /* etc */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the EditTexts and iterate through.  
If you find an empty item show the Toast:

```
EditText[] edits = {etFirstName, etLastName, etAddress, etCountry, etPostalCode};

for (EditText et : edits) {
    if (et.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Empty text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

change `this` to a valid `Context` if this code is not inside an sctivity class.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using TextUtils class like this :

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(yourEditText.getText()) && ...[rest of your editText views]) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter data ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also , in this case user can write only spaces in editText and it will still be valid which is not what we want so for checking that :

```
if (yourEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) { 
// we remove all spaces and if it's empty it means that user wrote only spaces
  Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter data ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```